# CSS Repeat the background from a particular point

Tags: html, css

I want the background to be displayed from the line drawn on the screenshot:

http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/4707/wjm7.png

I tried to use

```
background : ('path/to/image') 0 650px repeat-y
```

But it the light part of the image moves and it looks ugly. All I want is simply to background look on the site like on the screenshot, but without the dark part in the bottom. Thats why I want it to repeat from the red line.

Now the css is this way:

```
background : url('path/to/image') top center
```

Comment: Why not create a new picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can set px values instead of `top`

```
background : url('path/to/image') -430px center;
```

Repeating the background like this will not be possible. You'll just have to crop your image and use `repeat`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use two backgrounds. I.e. set the repeatable part as a background of the body and the other part as a background of your main container.